# Determine the infimum of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I consider the function $H: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
H(x,u,p) =  p(-xu + \frac{1}{2}u^2)
$$

I would like to find its infimum with respect to the second variable however there is one case that I do not understand.

First, I check if the function is convex and I see that it depends on the sign of $p$. For the case where $p\geq 0$ there is no ambiguity (either the function is convex and can be minimized, or it is constant equal to $0$).

However, for the case where $p<0$ I feel that my argument is not rigorous enough but I may be wrong.

The idea is that we have

$$
H(x,u,p) =  p(-x + \frac{1}{2}u)u
$$

Thus, for $u$ big enough the parenthesis is strictly positive, taking the limit as $u$ goes to $\infty$ we obtain that $H$ goes to $-\infty$ and this implies that its his infimum with respect to $u$.

I would like to know if this argument is valid for the part where $p<0$ please. Thank you a lot

Comment: Did you mean *infimum*?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes sorry… corrected !